# Movie clip is stabilized in preview, but not in render

Tags: rendering, tracking

I have a movie which I want to stabilize. After I open the movie in the movie clip editor, insert the marker, track it, enable the stabilization 2D, and view the stabilized result the movie clip looks fine. After I go to Compositor and make a standard setup (Movie clip -> Stabilization -> Compositing/Viewer) the clip is not well stabilized anymore in the render. I can see that settings from Stabilization 2D are taken into account (for example scale and offsets), but the marker is not staying still anymore and is jumping around in the render window. For some clips the stabilization works fine, and for others there is this difference between the clip preview and the render. What could be the reason for the difference between the movie clip preview and the render?

**Update:** I have added a link to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MipRihA3sZM), showing that when I move frame by frame the clip preview is stable, but the render is shaking.

**Update 2:** The link to the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YK9VdOJf0zrtVLXmQFpQ6RHRhyaLFZOm/view) and the [input video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zabqf134PXpNWotQCOKLObO-PQfB99rl/view).

Comment: I'm not sure if someone can help without your issued blend file, to see your setup and result.

Comment: I have added a link to the video, showing the process of stabilizing the video and the difference between the clip preview and the render.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for blend file ... your workflow is OK, when I mimic your workflow it works for me. So it is something that we don't see ... or can be specific to blender version.

Comment: The links to the blend file and the input video have been added.

Comment: @vklidu Thank you for your time, I have found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, it was somehow related to the format of the original movie clip. After I convert the video to MP4 H264 perceptually lossless format the problem is gone, the render shows exactly the same as the movie clip preview and in the resulting video the shaking is gone.

Comment: Great you solved it ... it was always better to export to PNG sequence for VFX :)